# Is it possible to catch exception thrown from base class constructor inside derived class constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

Suppose I have a following code

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        throw new SomeKindOfException();
    }  
}

class Derived : Base
{

}
```

and suppose I instantiate Derived class.

```
Derived d = new Derived();
```

In order for `Derived` class to be instantiated the `Base` class should be instantiated firstly right ? so is there any theoretical or practical way to catch an exception thrown from base class constructor in derived class constructor. I suppose there is not, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The constructor of `Base` is always executed before any code in the constructor of `Derived`, so no. (If you don't explicitly define a constructor in `Derived`, the C# compiler creates a constructor `public Derived() : base() { }` for you.) This is to prevent that you don't accidentally use an object that has not been fully instantiated yet.

What you can do is initialize part of the object in a separate method:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        throw new SomeKindOfException();
    }  
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }
        catch (SomeKindOfException)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

```
var obj = new Derived();
obj.Initialize();
```

Comment: how come I did not came up with that idea. but anyway thanks for the answer. this is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need, but my base constructor initializes some read-only properties based on a parameter passed in from the derived class, so the above solution wouldn't work for me. What I did was add a read-only Exception property to the base class that gets set in the catch clause within the constructor, and which the derived class can then  check in its own constructor and handle appropriately.

```
class Base
{
    public Base(string parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            // do something with parameter
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ExceptionProperty = exception;
        }
    }

    public Exception ExceptionProperty  { get; }
}

class Derived : Base("parameter")
{
    if (ExceptionProperty != null)
    {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```