# Can a base-class (constructor) detect if a derived constructor threw an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, constructor, try-catch

I wonder if a base class can detect (and react upon) exceptions thrown in a derived constructor.

In this somewhat artificial example, I would like to avoid the warning when the `Derived` instance cannot be constructed, because it cannot be closed by the user. I could wrap the derived constructor in a `try/catch` block, but I would have to require that for each derived constructor. Ideally, I would like to implement this in the base class itself. I have found how to catch a base-class constructor exception in the derived class ([How to catch a base class constructor's exception in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73550199/how-to-catch-a-base-class-constructors-exception-in-c)), but I would like something like the inverse of that.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    void close() {
        closed = true;
    }
    
    ~Base() {
        if (!closed) std::cout << "Warning: I should be closed!" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    bool closed = false;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() : Base() {
        throw 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Issues warning
    Base not_closed;

    // Issues no warning    
    Base().close();
    
    // How can I prevent a warning here?
    try {
        Derived derived;
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

*Update*: one alternative could be to skip calling `~Base`, but I understand that is not possible.

Comment: When the base class is being constructed the derived class does not yet exist.  Only after the base class constructor has run to successful completion is the derived class constructed.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, I am aware of that. I would not have to know in `Base()` - instead, it would be sufficient to know in `~Base()`, which is called well *after* `Base` has been constructed. I modified the question title.

Comment: if the base class needs to know about the derived you have a flaw in your design

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai can you point out the flaw in my design of the classes above?

Comment: This is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You only tell us about what you think is a solution (it isnt), but what the actual problem is you are trying to solve is unclear. why do you think you need to catch the exception? Why do you think the base needs to know?

Comment: If the derived constructor "fails" it can throw its own exception. E.g declare your own exception type and you can catch on that. But it is still not clear to me WHAT you want to achieve.

Comment: @PepijnKramer "If the derived constructor "fails" it can throw its own exception." thats what the code does, but OP wants to react on that exception in the base constructor, which isnt possible

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Thanks, I now understand his question. And indeed that is not possible with inheritance. For a case like this aggregation would be needed where Derived (is no longer derived) and aggregates base.

Comment: Your base class could have a member variable that the derived class is responsible for setting that indicates "everything is okay".  That member variable would default to "something has gone awry" state.

Comment: _"...it would be sufficient to know in `~Base()` ... "_ but why? The object is going to be destroyed as throwing in the constructor of derived will cause will cause the complete object to be destroyed.  So all that needs to be performed is any clean-up.

Comment: @RichardCritten people are saying this may be an xy-problem, but the code above is actually pretty close to what I have and need. I have a warning in `~Base` that logs "misuse" of the class (that is, destroying an instance before closing it first). And I would like to avoid the warning if the class is not being "misused" because closing is not even possible. That's all.

Comment: The usual pattern is either to automatically "close" (the resource) or `throw`  an exception in destructor of the object the owns the resource that needs to be cleaned up.  This way the user of the class (creator of the derived class) either does not have to concern themselves with clean up or they have to fix the problem as soon as they test their code.

Comment: @RichardCritten: right. Except that throwing in a destructor is not ideal, I understand. And I would need to avoid `throw`ing in case the derived constructor has thrown already, in which case we end up with the exact same question as we started with.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a base-class (constructor) detect if a derived constructor threw an exception?

No.

The base class constructor is executed before the derived class constructor. By the time you throw the exception, the base class subobject is already constructed.

Assuming you want to stay with inheritance you can turn the logic around to avoid the warning:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    void close() { closed = true; }
    void open() { closed = false; }
    ~Base() {
        if (!closed) std::cout << "Warning: I should be closed!" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    bool closed = true;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() : Base() {        
        throw 0;
        Base::open();
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        Derived derived;
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xhsbqjPqd)

The `Base` initializes `closed = true` and when constructing the `Derived` does not throw, it calls `open()`.

If you can give up on inheritance, make `Base` a member of `Derived` to be in control of order of initialization.